# is there a collection that the item will be automatically removed in some fixed time?

Tags: java, collections

for  example  ,when  I add  a  Object   to a List ,the  List can  automatically remove this  object  in  some near  future ?

Comment: Not in any standard lib, no. But you could easily build such a thing yourself, why not give it a try!?

Answer (score 1):

For your use case you should take a look at Google's Guava library:

> LoadingCache<String, String> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
> .expireAfterAccess(2,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
> .build(loader);

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you are asking (since the removal is not triggered by time), but you could create a sub-class of `LinkedHashMap` that may automatically remove the eldest entry when a new entry is added to the `Map`.

This is achieved by overriding `protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K,V> eldest)`.